# Upload video to Facebook from the server

Tags: facebook, video, upload, token

I have a problem when uploading videos to Facebook.

I use Facebook SDK for Android: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk to get the access token with the following permissions: "publish_stream","email","video_upload","publish_actions"

Then I send token to the server, which should upload the video. The server tries to upload video using following code:

```
string fullurl = string.Format("https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?title={0}&description={1}&access_token={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(description), token);
```

Facebook returns an error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(String address, String fileName)
```

But, when I check token with the following link: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=myToken Facebook returns user info. That means that token is valid. But, if this request returns error code, where I can find information about error codes?

This solution works perfectly for some users, for other users it works unstable ( 4 of 6 videos uploading failed. Facebook returns that: *"connection closed by remote server"*). And have not worked for some users with error: *"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".*

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve the problem. I have start using facebook SDK for .NET http://facebooksdk.net/ and it works for me.

```
      Facebook.FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(facebookEditTask.facebookToken);
      fb.PostCompleted += (o, e) =>
      {
           if (e.Cancelled || e.Error != null)
           {
                return;
           }

           var result = e.GetResultData();
           facebookVideoUrl = CreateLinkToVideo(result.ToString());
       };

       dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
       parameters.source = new FacebookMediaStream
       {
             ContentType = "video/mp4",
              FileName = Path.GetFileName(facebookEditTask.FilePath)
       }.SetValue(File.OpenRead(facebookEditTask.FilePath));

       parameters.message = fbMessage;

       Task t = fb.PostTaskAsync("me/videos",
                    new { message = fbMessage, parameters.source });
```